# What term predated "even" when referring to numbers?

Tags: etymology, numbers, mathematics

Had this posted on the Linguistics stackexchange, and was pointed here as a more appropriate spot to ask.

In doing some poking around in etymologies, I noticed that while "odd" in the sense of "odd number" is attested as early as c.1300 (and is in fact the original sense of the term), "even" in the sense of "even number" isn't attested until the mid-16th century. Do we have any examples of what terms (if any) were used to describe even numbers during that gap?

Comment: Even is found in this context as early as 1450 http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65413.html

Comment: You may wish to post this question to the History of Science and Mathematics stackexchange site, as well: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The _OED_'s earliest citation is from a1398.

Comment: Sounds like I should just submit a correction to Etymonline then, haha. Thanks, James and ermanen!

Answer (score 2):

There is no gap in attestations for *even* and *odd*:

> … þe moones [Mrg: monþes; L menses] ben [*euene oþir odde*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED30189), for an euene mone answeriþ to an odde moneþ and an odde mone to an euene moneþ.
>
> Oon is moder of pluralite and cause of [*euene and odde*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED30189) [L imparitatis], for if þou settest oon to an odde nombre nedes þu makest an euene nombre. — Bartholomaeus, *De Proprietatibus Rerum* (ME translation), ca. 1398.

In Old English there is the rare term [*ofertæl*](http://oldenglishthesaurus.arts.gla.ac.uk/category/?id=4956) for an odd number, an “over number.” For *tæl* think of the expression *all told*. This was eventually replaced by borrowing from Old Norse [*oddatala*](https://is.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oddatala), which is still Icelandic for an odd number. An even number is a *slétt tal*, ‘even, smooth’.

I was unable to determine whether Old English even numbers were *efen*, but I have no reason to doubt it, given the same word/concept from Scandinavia until you hit the High German of the south.

The underlying metaphor behind *odd* is ‘angle, point of land’, so odd numbers are pointy and angled while even ones are smooth and flat. Both Low German and Dutch use *even*, but odd numbers are *uneven*. High German goes for the vertical dimension: even numbers are *gerade*, ‘straight’ and *ungerade*.

Comment: Some of continental Scandinavia goes the High German way too (probably through borrowing, I imagine): in Danish/Norwegian, even numbers are _lige/like_ ‘straight’ and odd ones are _ulige/ulike_ ‘un-straight’. In Swedish, though, they’re _jämn_ ‘even’ and _udda_ ‘odd’. (Similarly in Icelandic, you can also call them _jöfn töl_ and _ójöfn töl_.)

Comment: Speaking of borrowing, Norwegian also uses _partall_ straight from Latin. https://no.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partall